# Self/own implementation of smart pointers

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I'm trying to code my own implementation of shared pointers (for fun/challenge) but I hit a dead end after I cannot make the constructor accept any (auto) type of pointer variable. The problem is, for now I can only make my own smart pointer points to a certain data-type (class P) but I want it to be able to point to any data type however the problem is I need to specify the data type in the constructor arguments.

Code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <memory>

    class P //dummy class
    {
        int x;
    public:
        P() : x(42) {}
        ~P() {}

        void print()
        {
            std::cout<<"Address = "<< this << "\n";
        }
    };

    class P2 //dummy class 2
    {
    public:
        P2() {}
        ~P2() {}

        void print()
        {
            std::cout<<"Address = "<< this << "\n";
        }
    };

    class SmartP
    {

        P *ptr;
    public:

        SmartP(P *p) : ptr(p) {}
        ~SmartP()
        {
            delete ptr;
        }

        P& operator* ()
        {
            return *ptr;
        }

        P* operator-> ()
        {    
            return ptr;
        }
    };

    void rawPointer()
    {
        P *p(new P);
        p->print();
        delete p;   //when removed, next allocated address will be different
    }

    void smartPointerOwn()
    {
        SmartP spo(SmartP(new P));
        //This should also work but currently it does not: SmartP spo(SmartP(new P2));
        spo->print();
        //Do not need a delete
    }

    void smartPointer()
    {
        std::unique_ptr<P> sp(new P);
        sp->print();
        //Do not need a delete
    }

    int main()
    {
        rawPointer();
        smartPointerOwn();
        smartPointer();

        std::cin.get(); //Prevent exiting console prematurely
        return 0;
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is _template_.

Comment: That's what templates are for.

Comment: You even used a templated type here `std::unique_ptr<P>`...

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ More precisely, you question doesn't show any evidence of having studied existing standard smart pointers and their workings (or at least their outward interface).

Comment: These functions
        rawPointer();
        smartPointerOwn();
        smartPointer();
Is just a way to show the difference between using raw pointers, own implementation of smart pointer and actual smart pointer.

Answer (score 0):

here some basic example to help start you off. Like already mentioned in the comments you should first check some existing smart pointer implementations.
This example is very incomplete - for ex. the reference counting is missing (if shared pointer wanted). But it gives you an idea. I hope it helps a little bit.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class  SmartP {
 public:
  SmartP() : p{nullptr} {}
  SmartP(T* pp) : p{pp} {}
  ~SmartP() { delete p; }

  // dereferencing operators
  friend T& operator*(const SmartP<T>& sp) { return *(sp.p); }
  T& operator->() const { return *p; }

  // get the raw pointer
  T* get() const { return p; }

 private:
  T* p;
};

int main() {

  SmartP<int> p{new int{3}};
  cout << *p << endl;

  *p = 4;
  cout << *p << endl;
}
```

Comment: Ok so far so good, but when I try to make it point to a dummy class with a method, it results to an error stating "result of 'operator->()' yields non-pointer result".
For now, having it act as a unique pointer is a start.

Comment: Ah nevermind, fixed it.
Fix:
    T* operator->() const { return ptr; }
    T& get() const { return *ptr; }